# Using SD library in a ESP-IDF project on ESP32

Tags: sd-card, esp32, makefile

I just started to move from the **Arduino** firmware to the **esp-idf** firmware.
I read [that link](https://esp-idf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-guides/build-system.html). I learn that I have to include libraries creating a component files, with a `component.mk` file, `*.c`, `*.cpp` files and an `include/` folder for `*.h` files.
That was ok for most of libraries I had to include, except for the SD card library, more precisely the `Sd2PinMap.h` header.

It seems that **ESP32** is not recognized:

```
$(IDF-PATH)/Project/components/SD/include/Sd2PinMap.h:510:2: error:
#error Architecture or board not supported.
```

but with the **Arduino** firmware, there were no problems.

I checked `make menuconfig` options, but I didn't find a way to make it work for an ESP32 board... Any ideas ?

Comment: So, this question is about non-Arduino hardware running non-Arduino firmware?

Comment: It's about moving from Arduino, to another firmware. I was thinking that arduino.stackexchange was more appropriate for this than stackoverflow, which is too broad. Where am I supposed to ask this ?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I wasn't saying you can't ask, I was just clarifying what your issue was

Comment: espressif esp32 forum https://www.esp32.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the solution was simple, I just had to pull the [update](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/SD) for the SD Card library, mine was outdated. Thank you all.